# Does creating a temp table cause the pg_class table to fragment

Tags: performance, postgresql

MS-SQL developer on this end working in a Postgres shop (PG 8.4 and PG 9.4)

Another developer mentioned as a reason for not using temp tables in Postgres SQL is that it will cause fragmentation in the Postgres system tables (pg_class specifically) leading to performance degradation.  Is this true?

Cheers

Comment: not sure about the fragmentation but on postgresql you almost never need temporary tables. There's always a way to write a query without using them

Comment: Thanks for the response. Temp tables, just like CTEs are just tools/techniques.  A carpenter picks up a circle saw, jigsaw or an oscillating saw depending on the need.  Programmers aren't much different :).

Comment: Right so think of using a temporary table like using a circular saw to cut circle! despite the name circular saws are used for cutting straight lines.

Answer (score 3):

*Fragmentation* is a rather meaningless term when applied to a database table, as they always consist of blocks of a fixed size (8 KB in PostgreSQL).

What is true is that using a temporary table will create entries in system catalog tables and indexes like `pg_class` which will be deleted when the temporary table goes away. If you do *a lot* of that, the same thing could happen as with any other table that is heavily updated: autovacuum may not be able to keep up, and your system catalog tables and their indexes might get bloated.

There is [a proposal on pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160729141552.4062e19b%40fujitsu) right now to invent a new kind of temporary table that avoids this kind of problem.

However, unless you use really a lot of temporary tables all the time, there is no need to worry. Just use them when you need to!